# Do I really need Ramps 1.4 for laser engraver

Tags: arduino-uno, a4988

I'm making 2-axis laser engraver like system. Arduino waits command from pc, on receive moves laser to next coordinate and send current coordinate to pc.

I have 3 step motors and I'm controlling them with Arduino Uno which is connected to A4988 drivers which is on breadboard. But almost all samples using Ramps. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramps 1.4 is one of the proof of concept standards for 3D printer systems. It is a motherboard mostly runs Marlin firmware on it. I advice to to take a look at the firmware if you didn't yet. It is also supporting many motherboards, hardware.

When you open the `configuration.h` file in the firmware and search for this definition `#define MOTHERBOARD` you will be seeing many options available.

After all, the firmware is the key factor. It contains many engineering solutions in it. So, you shouldn't re-invent the wheel.
All you have to do is to adapt it with some tweaks as per your design specifications.

But, I would worry more about your motherboard (Arduino Uno)
if your design is relatively simple, using less memory and IO pins, it may be just fine. I would consider Mega 2560 instead If I were you.

Good luck with your project.